# How can i read and modify a json file in scala spark play

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I want to read a JSON file and create a class/object that saved all label and value from every JSON's vector/record. Then I want to modify some values (or the JSON structure) and get this modified JSON file to Http request with play/spark/scala.

So how can I fill my class's variables with the json's values?

For example, I have this JSON file

```
   [
  {
    "ser": 345,
    "City": "New York",
    "Gen": 1
  },
  {
    "ser": 55,
    "City": "New York",
    "Gen": 2
  },
  {
    "ser": 19,
    "City": "New York",
    "Gen": 3
  }
 ]
```

My goal is create a class like this

```
class Book(ser:Integer, city:String, Gen:Integer)
{
   //TODO
}
```

That takes every value of ser, city and gen, from the json for all the records in the file.
Than I want to modify the structure or values of the json, save and answer with the new file to a Http request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have this class

```
case class Book(ser: Int, city: String, gen: Int)
```

you can perform the JSON conversion using Play's JSON serialization/deserialization by implementing a formatter:

```
implicit val bookFormat: Format[Book] = {
  ((JsPath \ "ser").format[Int] and
    (JsPath \ "City").format[String] and
    (JsPath \ "Gen").format[Int]
    ) (Book.apply, unlift(Book.unapply))
}

// returns a sequence of Book objects
val books = Json.parse(bookJson).as[Seq[Book]]
// modify your books...
(...)
// convert back to Json
val json = Json.toJson(books)
```

Comment: Thanks!
Another question, my Json has more variables then 3 (not only city, ser gen but also address money etc.). Can i take just 3-4 variables from the json or i should initialize all the variables?

Comment: As `Format` is implemented above it only takes the specified three entries from the JSON and ignores the rest. So if you only need these three you're fine. But you also have to be aware that when serializing your object only these three values will be in the resulting JSON and it will not be the same as the original JSON.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain this (Book.apply, unlift(Book.unapply) ?

Comment: Sorry i'm new scala/play/spark' user so i need help.
Can you explain better? How can format take values from the json file?
And for example, how can i modify my JSON in a JSON file like this?

Comment: [
  {
  "label": [1,2,3],
  "values": [
  {
   "label":"New York"
   "values":["200","10","66"]
  }, 
  {
   "label":"London"
   "values":["500","150","46"]
  
  },
  {
   "label":"London"
   "values":["500","150","46"]
  
  }
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
 ]

  }
]

Comment: The `apply` and `unapply` methods are automatically created on case classes. They are used to create an object for a given list of arguments (apply, which is similar to a constructor) and extract a tuple of the objects members (unapply). The default implementation of unapply on case classes returns an Option of a tuple of values, but in our case we just need the tuple which the `unlift` is doing for us. It basically converts a function which returns an `Option[Result]` to a function returning an `Result`.

Comment: and i take the json input file with rdd spark

Comment: Can you provide some code showing how you get the JSON from Spark?

Comment: ` val dataFile = "resources/dataset-json/dataset.json"
  lazy val rdd = SparkCommons.sqlContext.read.format("json").load(dataFile)`

Comment: News?
I create and fill the book class with the play's format method.

Comment: Do you really need Spark for doing this? Is there a reason why you can't just read the file into a string and use the code as described in the answer to modify your JSON?

Comment: I need to use spark for quering the json.
Now i create the class that take the json (with format method).
Then i need to create a new json in this form (How can i mek this?):

[ { "label": [1,2,3], "values": [ { "label":"New York" "values":["200","10","66"] }, { "label":"London" "values":["500","150","46"] }, { "label":"London" "values":["500","150","46"] } . . . . . ] } ]

And then i want to spark-quering this new file (and answer with this new JSON quering).
Do you uderstand? :)

Comment: One way to do this is to create a class that represents the structure of your desired JSON output. Then based on your input data you create an instance of the class and use a formatter to generate the JSON output. Or use the `JsObject, JsArray, JsString` etc. to create the JSON as described in the docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson

Comment: I wrote something in the comment down... Did you see?

Answer (score 0):

Without adding further dependencies to your project, since you're already using Play, you should take a look at [Play's json serialization / deserialization capabilities](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson)

Answer (score 0):

Josef I'm writing here because is better.

Ok, so now I create the class that take the json (with format method). I have the seq, and i can make something like this:

```
books(9).city //return the city's value of the seq Book in 9 position of the seq
```

Ok so now I want to create a new Json with this structure:

```
[ { "label": [1,2,3] //that is the Gen value, 
     "values": [ 
                 { "label":"New York" 
                   "values":["200","10","66"]  //is the ser about all Gen (for example 200 is ser is for label/gen 1 .. 10 is for label/gen 2 etc.
                 },
                { "label":"London" 
                  "values":["500","150","46"] 
                }, 
                { "label":"London" 
                  "values":["500","150","46"] 
                }, 
                .
                . 
                . 
                . 
                . 
               ] 
  } 
]
```

That is different from the structure of the JSON input. I think that could be helpful create this new class:

```
class New_book(
label_gen:List[String], 
values_gen:List[Libri], 
label:String, 
values:List[Int]  
 )
```

Then i want to fill this new class with the book's seq ( that is this: 
"val books = Json.parse(JsonString).as[Seq[Libri]]" if you remember ).

After this, I will be querying the new Json with spark, and answer with it to an Http request.

I hope I was understood now :D

Comment: The new class doesn't reflect the structure of the JSON. I'm assuming that the `Libri` class already represents elements of the inner `values` array. The `label` and `values` members are then not necessary.

Comment: I don't understand...sorry values_gen is List[Book].
Now, how can i make this conversion?

Comment: Having a `case class LabelValues(label: String, values: Seq[Int]) and assuming `books` is a `Seq[Book]` use `groupBy` (to combine all books for specific city into a sequence) in combination with `map` to transform your books, sth. like this: `books.groupBy(b => b.city).map{ case(city, cityBooks) => LabelValues(city, cityBooks.map(b => b.ser))}`  which should give you the data needed for the inner `values` part of your JSON structure (i.e. a sequence of entries, each entry consisting of the city name and the ser numbers).

Comment: I think that the result seq will be like this

`Label(1,2,3 //all the gen value) values( city("london"), ser(10,200,30 //value of ser that are in relation with gen) city("NewYork"), ser(10,30,2).....)`

It's different from you list. Thank you for the patience :)

Comment: I have another question, can i convert the book seq  `(val books = Json.parse(bookJson).as[Seq[Book]]) ` in Rdd (because i need to query the input json, before modify the final structure.

Comment: Ehi @Josef i need the last aid.
Your list is like this:

` List(Jit(New York,List(0, 0)), Jit(London,List(186, 17, 8, 5, 2)), Jit(BALI,List(997, 124, 35, 47, 2, 5, 1, 2)), Jit(Rome,List(872, 401, 84, 85)), Jit(Milan,List(31)))`

But i need (after modify the json),  list like this: 

`Label(1,2,3 //all the gen value) values( city("london"), ser(10,200,30 //value of ser that are in relation with gen) city("NewYork"), ser(10,30,2).....)`

how can I fix your conversion? Hope that you'll answer for the last time :)

Comment: Not really sure if I understand the question. The code I provided returned the data in a structure which is similar to what's expected in the JSON output. There may be some differences regarding naming of the properties, wrapping into objects etc. - adjust what's in `.map()` to fit your needs. To make it simple if you need the gen values as a list, use `books.map(book => book.gen)` which gives you a sequence of all gen numbers. It requires traversing the list twice, but maybe that's not a problem. Take this list and combine it with the other values into another object you then convert to JSON.

Comment: ok so now, I have list of all gen value Label(1,2,3) and i have another with all the other element group by city
 `List(Jit(New York,List(0, 0)), Jit(London,List(186, 17, 8, 5, 2)), Jit(BALI,List(997, 124, 35, 47, 2, 5, 1, 2)), Jit(Rome,List(872, 401, 84, 85)), Jit(Milan,List(31)))`

How can i aggregate this two list in another one like this:

Label(1,2,3 //all the gen value), values { [city("london"), ser(10,200,30)], city("NewYork"), ser(10,30,2)].....}
Do you understand now?

Comment: List(Label(1,2,3 //all the gen value), values { [city("london"), ser(10,200,30)], city("NewYork"), ser(10,30,2)].....})

I wrote here (again) the list that i'll expected

Comment: so, have you got the solution?

Comment: I need this last help...please

Comment: Just use another class with these two lists as members. I only want to give you hints on how to implement this and I don't want to write all the code for you. If you are looking for this SO is not the right place. I recommend reading the docs as e.g. mentioned in the other answer. Just try to start with simple examples and understand them and then continue with more complex examples. There is plenty of documentation out there. It may take longer in the beginning but it's an investment in your future which is worth it.